# How to determine the maximal number of voxels a ray may pass in a voxel volume?

Tags: math, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

Assuming a volume of voxels (x, y, z have same size => cube) and a ray passing through that voxel volume, how to determine the maximal number of voxels a ray may pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider plane and 2d square pixels (chess board), we can see that ray can pass through at most `2*N-1` pixels, if we count true intersections (for example, starting point 0, -.5 and direction Pi/4) and `3*N-2`, if we count touched (by corner) cells.

It is rather hard to imagine 3d case in the head :), but I suspect that ray parallel to the main diagonal, can intersect `3 * N - 2` cells, when ray pass cells in order (0,0,0)-(1,0,0)-(1,1,0)-(1,1,1) etc

Addition. Quick silly ray-tracing modeling shows that `3 * N - 2` value is possible:

```
var
  sx, sy, sz: Double;
  x, y, z: Double;
  ox, oy, oz, nx, ny, nz, Cnt: Integer;
begin
  // starting point coordinate
  sx := 0;
  sy := 0.7;
  sz := 0.7;
  // current coordinates
  X := sx;
  Y := sy;
  z := sz;
  // previous cell indexes
  ox := Floor(X);
  oy := Floor(Y);
  oz := Floor(z);
  Cnt := 1;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d: (%d, %d, %d)', [Cnt, ox, oy, oz]));
  repeat
    // new cell indexes
    nx := Floor(X);
    ny := Floor(Y);
    nz := Floor(z);
    // if cell changes
    if (nx > ox) or (ny > oy) or (nz > oz) then begin
      Inc(Cnt);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d: (%d, %d, %d)', [Cnt, nx, ny, nz]));
    end;
    ox := nx;
    oy := ny;
    oz := nz;
    // do small step in main diagonal direction
    X := X + 0.03;
    Y := X + 0.03;
    z := z + 0.03;
  until (X > 4) or (Y > 4) or (z > 4);
```

gives output with 4 * 3 - 2 intersected voxels:

```
1: (0, 0, 0)
2: (0, 0, 1)
3: (0, 1, 1)
4: (1, 1, 1)
5: (1, 1, 2)
6: (1, 2, 2)
7: (2, 2, 2)
8: (2, 2, 3)
9: (2, 3, 3)
10: (3, 3, 3)
```